# System largest font size cropping wpf menu

Tags: wpf, font-size

From the Display Properties dialog in the Control Panel, if I change the font size property to Extra Large Fonts, the menus in my WPF application become cropped as shown in the image below:

[image]

How do I fix this?

TIA.

Comment: please post the xaml for the menu and grid (if you are using a grid)

Comment: Your comment gave me an idea on where to look.  Menu.Height is being fixed to 25.  Will change this to Auto and MinHeight of 25 and see it goes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grid rows containing menus were being set to fixed heights.  Changing the height of these rows to Auto solved this problem.  Thanks to BalamBalam for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

If should set that with top margin negative